# 'IN' & 'NOT IN' in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have tested the following query in LINQPad and it runs fine, but VS2010 doesn't like it.

```
var topJobs = from j in streetlightDBEntities.Job
    let mjobid = from m in streetlightDBEntities.Job.Include("Streetlight")
                 where m.Streetlight.StreetlightId == j.Streetlight.StreetlightId
                 orderby m.DateCompleted descending
                 select m.JobId
        where mjobid.Take(5).Contains(j.JobId)
        select j.JobId;

var notTopJobs = streetlightDBEntities.Job.Where(c => !topJobs.Contains(c.JobId));
```

I got the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[String](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Are you targeting .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**Queryable.Any`<TSource>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338.aspx).

Instead of this:

```
var notTopJobs = streetlightDBEntities
      .Job
      .Where(c => !topJobs.Contains(c.JobId));
```

Do this:

```
var notTopJobs = streetlightDBEntities
      .Job
      .Where(c => !topJobs.Any(x => x.JobId == c.JobId))
```

Do the same for your original query.

Comment: error with x.JobId:
'string' does not contain a definition for 'JobId' and no extension method 'JobId' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Comment: well then your new first query is wrong. i based `topJobs` on the query you had originally, which selected `JobId`. Does your `topTops` query return `JobId` in the select/projection?